# grep pattern on multiple columns but one

Tags: grep

I have a tab delimiter file with ~10,000 columns.
I want to filter rows where some columns contain pattern. But I don't want to have the grep checking first column.

```
$ cut -f2,1691-1725 myfile.txt
1402138 2331    2331
1402422 181     630
1402795 1401            1401
1405425 2331
1405771 1727    1727
1406169 2331    2331
1406475 2252    2252
1408259 1744    1744
```

I tried this :

```
cut -f2,1691-1725 myfile.txt | grep -E '^140|^141|^143|^144|^145|^146|^148|^149' > myoutput.txt
```

but it keeps all because grep also applies on first column

Desired output :

```
1402795 1401            1401
```

I search a way with awk but can't find easy one without listing each columns

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data always starts at the exact same character column, you could use `^.{n}` to skip `n` characters, then start matching.

```
$ cat myfile.txt
1402138 2331    2331
1402422 181     630
1402795 1401            1401
1405425 2331
1405771 1727    1727
1406169 2331    2331
1406475 2252    2252
1408259 1744    1744

$ cat myfile.txt | grep -E '^.{24}(140|141|143|144|145|146|148|149)'
1402795 1401            1401
```

The pattern above first matches any 24 characters (except newline) since the start of the line, then tries to match `(140|141|143|144|145|146|148|149)` starting from character position 25.

In this scenario `(140|141|143|144|145|146|148|149)` could be simplified to `14[01345689]` as well.

Comment: This what I was looking for !!! It worked without the ^ ``cat myfile.txt |  grep -E '.{8}(14[01345689])' ``
Thank you !!!!!!!!

Comment: Do note that without the `^` it might find a match in the 3rd or 4th column as well, not just the 2nd. It will just skip the 1st. If this is the intent, then matching without `^` is fine. I just want you to be aware of the different behaviour when in-/excluding `^`.

Comment: Correct, I want to find the match in every column except first. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question, and from what I can see from your provided input and output, you have the following requirement:

**Question:** *Provide a command that, given a set of column-numbers, returns all rows where each column is empty and/or matches a given regular expression*

When talking about columns and regular expressions, the best answer is clearly awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a[2]; for(i=1691;i<=1725;++i) a[i]}
     BEGIN{ere="^14[01345689]"}
     BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     {f=1;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if(i in a) if(!($i ~ ere)) f=($i=="")}
     f' file
```

**How does it work:**

1. **`BEGIN{a[2]; for(i=1691;i<=1725;++i) a[i]}`:** Define an associative array `a` which is indexed by the columns of interest. In this case, those are `2, 1691-1725`
2. **`BEGIN{ere="^14[01345689]"}`:** Define the regular expression that each column should match
3. **`BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}`:** Define the input and output field separator to be the <tab>-character
4. **`f=1;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if(i in a) if(!($i ~ ere)) f=($i=="")`:**
   Each time a line is read, perform the following actions:

   1. **`f=1`:** Set the variable `f` equal to 1. This will be used as a flag to determine whether a line should be printed
   2. **`for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) ...`:** loop over all fields
   3. **`... if(i in a)...`:** and check if the field is a field of interest
   4. **`... if(!($i ~ ere)) f=($i=="")`:** if the field is a field of interest and if the field *does not* match the regular expression, then set the flag `f` to ZERO or not ZERO depending if the field is empty or not.
5. **`f`:** If the flag `f` is not zero, print the current line. (This is a shorthand for `(f!=0){print $0}`

Comment: Thank you kvantour ! The solution of skipping n char for grep suits me better ,

Answer (score 0):

For filtering on the values of a certain column, you might better use `awk` (`grep` is better suited for filtering the entire line), something like this:

```
prompt> cat file.txt
Name Value1 Value2
a 1 2
b 2 5
c 5 1

prompt> awk -F " " '{if ($2==1) print $0}' file.txt
a 1 2
```